# How to use an array in three.js instead of MeshFaceMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new learner of three.js. There are some problems with MeshFaceMaterial.So anyone can help me in this case.i'll be very thankful to him.

Comment: Add more details, like the error descriptions, your implementation etc. Without that its hard to understand the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `MeshFaceMaterial` is deprecated. You can add multiple materials to a single mesh like this:

```
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ material1, material2 ] );
```

`three.js R94`